# filtrar una lista de fechas

Tags: kotlin, filtro

tengo una lista de fechas en la variable getList

```
val getList : List<LocalDate> = getDatesInBetween(startDate, endDate) as List<LocalDate> //[2022-07-20, 2022-07-21, 2022-07-22, 2022-07-23]
```

y lo que quiero es filtrar todas esas fechas en mi lista data para obtener solo los items que contengan dichas fechas de getList

```
for (item in data.filter { it.fecha.contains(getList) } ){

        itemsTable.deleteBodyRows()

        val itemdetails = PdfPTable(1)
continue.....
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

la solucion esta en pasar la lista a String

```
        val filterData = (getList).toString()
for (item in data.filter { it.fecha in filterData } ){
        
                    itemsTable.deleteBodyRows()
            
            continue.....
 }
```

Comment: ¡No olvides explicar el funcionamiento del código, además de [aceptar](/help/accepted-answer) tu respuesta! _Esta respuesta se reportó como de baja calidad debido a su extensión y contenido._